How to show outputs of a ":!cmd" command on a new screen, rather than at the bottom of my screen?
Whenever I type a shell command, like:
:!ls

Neovim will display it at the bottom of my screen. I'd like it to, instead, clear the whole window, and display it at the top. Is that possible?

Does this plugin work for Neovim? https://github.com/AndrewRadev/bufferize.vim

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

@VivianDeSmedt sorry for the delay, I didn't get the notifications, thanks for pinging me.

I would do:
:terminal ls

Or its short form:
:te ls

This start a terminal buffer and run the ls command in it.
Since it is a terminal buffer you can switch to:

Terminal mode using a (or i or A or even I)
Normal mode using Ctrl \Ctrl n

In Normal mode you can navigate into the buffer using Neovim buffer functionalities.

The full command is :terminal.

Thanks, this does work, but it is still not clear how to go back. These commands don't work on my setup, so I've done tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>, but pressing Esc does nothing. So I can't go back to the original screen at all. Am I missing something?

Thanks the feedback :-) To go back to the original screen you can close this terminal buffer with the :bd command.

The :bd command just exists neovim entirely here?
